# storing data into a file rather than returning to the terminal

Tags: file, python-3.x, storing-information

i have this function: `write_reversed_file(input_filename, output_filename)` that writes to the given output file the contents of the given input file with the lines in reversed order. i just need the output to be written to the file (`output_filename`) rather than to the terminal (python shell).

the only part im missing is to store the output into the file.
i successfully managed to complete the reversing lines part.

```
def write_reversed_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    for line in reversed(list(open(filename))):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Shell output redirection, as in `python foo.py > output.txt`, might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_reversed_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    s = ""
    f = open(input_filename,"r")
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    for line in reversed(lines):
        s+=line.rstrip()+"\n"
    f = open(outPutFile.txt,"w")
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use 'with open as' format when working with files since it is automatically closing the file for us. (as recommended in docs.python.org)

```
def write_reversed_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
        with open(input_filename, 'r') as r:
            for line in reversed(list(r.read())):
                f.write(line)

write_reversed_file("inputfile.txt", "outputfile.txt")
```