# reading a file and writing in reverse

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read a file and write on with reverse lines. Here is my code so far:

```
def write_reversed_file(input_filename, output_filename):
"""Writes a reverse file"""
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:
        data = input_file.readlines()
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        return output_file.reversed(data)

try:
    write_reversed_file('data.txt', 'reversed.txt')
    print(open('reversed.txt').read())
except IOError:
    print ("Error: can't find file or read data"
```

Comment: what do you want from this community? Your question does not ask for anything.

Comment: sorry i was just wondering how to read a file and write a reversed version of it

Comment: Seems like homework and others may have asked it before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586063/storing-data-into-a-file-rather-than-returning-to-the-terminal

Comment: `output_file.reversed(data)` is invalid. See [the python tutorial on file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Do you mean the order of the lines reversed, or the characters in the lines themselves reversed, or both?

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking anything!!! Also, you should try to find the answer by your means or on StackOverflow before asking people to fix your code.

Well, your second half is wrong.

```
 with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
  for i in reversed(data):
    output_file.write(i)
```